# does a no-cache html stop server side caching or just browser caching?

Tags: html, caching, server-side

I got a client who has server side caching where stuff expires in 3 days.

SO the client clears browser cache and still gets old stuff from the server.

Will a meta tag no-cache stop the server from caching? or will in only stop client side caching?

Comment: The server should respect the header if it's aware of it.  It depends on what part of the server is doing the caching.  If it's just the web server, it will probably respect it.  If it's something further into the server, it might not know about the header.

Comment: So its not black and white and just take all the measures to stop caching and hope?

Answer (score 0):

To cache control the best way ever is only the server configuration, maybe you have a proxy and it is mantain a cache too.

I happy with server (page or web server app) configuration, like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

I hope help you